# Disable button when modifying

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a table of clients and in each row i have clients informations and  modify botton. when the user click on modify, a bootsrapp modal appear and display all information.
I would like to disable only the current button just after  clicking  on modify, and when the user close the modal this button return enabled. Notice that i install this application on a server so many users can access to the application at the same time, so when button is disabled for all users.

I tried this solution: the idea is when  clicking  at modify and the modal opens, the user click at the chekbox to disable the button, this works, but only at the current PC, for the other users its enabled.

```
<button ng-disabled="checked" ng-click="modify()" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#squarespaceModal"></button> 

<div class="modal fade" id="squarespaceModal" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="false">
.......

<input type="checkbox" ng-model="cheked">
</div>
```

I work with angularjs, but if this is not possible with it, no problem if it's with jquery or javascript.
Many thanks.

Comment: this is not a angularjs problem, you may resolve this problem in server back end, in which language did you develop your server?
when user click to botton you must make a $http request to server and update the value of botton as disabled and for all user it will be displayed disabled.

Comment: I worked with spring boot and rest Api (JEE).

Comment: ok, are you able to make a http request when a user click at botton? so if I were you I made this in these steps:
when a user click at botton call server to check if any user clicked before, if not in that case I set state of that variable true and then display the modal.
after modal closed i recall server to reset value of variable.

it's clear?

Comment: Ahh ok, just how call server to check if any user clicked before?

Comment: @Gary - if you aren't using UI Bootstrap, then you should be.  Check it out here: https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#modal